# How do I compile a QT Application that is located in a folder that has spaces in the path?

Tags: c++, qt, build, release

**Update:** I am not asking how I add a path to the .pro file that has spaces in it.  I am asking Why will my project not compile and how do I fix it when I am getting the following errors.

I have a QT project stored in `C:\My Program\CPU Analysis\` .  When I try to build my project under Release, I get two errors.  The first error is:

`D9024: unrecognized source file type 'C:\My'`.

I believe this error is because the compiler is not reading the entire path, but rather it is reading just a part of the path up to the space.  The second error is:

`C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Analysis\main.cpp': No such file or directory.`

Again, this is because the compiler is only reading part of the path.  How do I get the compiler to read the entire path?

Comment: That's why in general spaces in paths are a bad idea.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that the source file is stored in the project wrong. Try removing the source file and adding again.

Comment: please share your pro file if you are using Creator